# why std::vector::push_back much slower than a manual implementation?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I wanted to write a dynamic array for trivial type (then I can use memcpy or sth to optimize), but when I compare its efficiency to `std::vector`, I found its `push_back` function is twice as efficient as a`std::vector`.

That's so strange, I read source code of MSVC STL to find why, but in vain.

my code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Array {
    static_assert((std::is_trivial_v<T>), "Array requires type to be trivial.");
    T* m_p;
    size_t m_cap, m_siz;
private:
    void increase(size_t new_cap) {
        ASSERT(new_cap > m_cap);
        if (new_cap < m_cap + m_cap / 2)new_cap = m_cap + m_cap / 2;
        T* new_p = (T*)realloc(m_p, sizeof(T) * new_cap);
        ASSERT(new_p);
        m_p = new_p;
        m_cap = new_cap;
    }
public:
    Array() : m_siz(0), m_cap(0), m_p(nullptr) {}
    ~Array() { if (m_p)free(m_p); }
    Array(const Array& x) {
        m_cap = m_siz = x.m_siz;
        m_p = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * m_siz);
        memcpy(m_p, x.m_p, sizeof(T) * m_siz);
    }
    Array(Array&& x) {
        m_cap = x.m_cap;
        m_siz = x.m_siz;
        m_p = x.m_p;
        x.m_p = nullptr;
        x.m_cap = x.m_siz = 0;
    }
    Array& operator=(const Array& x) {
        m_cap = m_siz = x.m_siz;
        m_p = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * m_siz);
        memcpy(m_p, x.m_p, sizeof(T) * m_siz);
    }
    Array& operator=(Array&& x) {
        m_cap = x.m_cap;
        m_siz = x.m_siz;
        m_p = x.m_p;
        x.m_p = nullptr;
        x.m_cap = x.m_siz = 0;
    }
    void push_back(const T& x) {
        if (m_siz == m_cap)increase(m_cap + 1);
        m_p[m_siz++] = x;
    }
    void reserve(size_t cap) {
        if (cap > m_cap)
            increase(cap);
    }
    void resize(size_t siz, const T& val = T{}) {
        if (siz > m_siz) {
            if (siz > m_cap)increase(siz);
            for (size_t i = m_siz; i < siz; i++)
                m_p[i] = val;
        }
        m_siz = siz;
    }
    void shrink_to_fit() {
        m_p = realloc(m_p, m_siz * sizeof(T));
        m_cap = m_siz;
    }
    T& operator[](size_t pos) { ASSERT(pos < m_siz); return m_p[pos]; }
    const T& operator[](size_t pos) const { ASSERT(pos < m_siz); return m_p[pos]; }
    size_t size()const { return m_siz; }
    size_t capacity()const { return m_cap; }
    void clear() { m_siz = 0; }
};

#define N 10000
#define M 100000
template<typename T>
int test() {
    int t = clock();
    T v;
    v.reserve(M);
    for (int t = 0; t < N; t++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            v.push_back(i);
        //v.resize(M);

        //for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            //v[i] = -i;
        v.clear();
    }
    return clock() - t;
}
int main() {
    int t1 = test<std::vector<int>>();
    int t2 = test<Array<int>>();

    printf("vector:%dms.\nArray:%dms.\n", t1, t2);
}
```

result(Release in VS2019):

```
vector:1043ms.
Array:547ms.
```

This is the invoke chain of `std::vector::pushback`(MSVC):

```cpp
    void push_back(const _Ty& _Val) { // insert by moving into element at end, provide strong guarantee
        emplace_back(_STD move(_Val));
    }

    template <class... _Valty>
    decltype(auto) emplace_back(_Valty&&... _Val) {
        // insert by perfectly forwarding into element at end, provide strong guarantee
        auto& _My_data   = _Mypair._Myval2;
        pointer& _Mylast = _My_data._Mylast;
        if (_Mylast != _My_data._Myend) {
            return _Emplace_back_with_unused_capacity(_STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
        }

        _Ty& _Result = *_Emplace_reallocate(_Mylast, _STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
#if _HAS_CXX17
        return _Result;
#else // ^^^ _HAS_CXX17 ^^^ // vvv !_HAS_CXX17 vvv
        (void) _Result;
#endif // _HAS_CXX17
    }


    template <class... _Valty>
    decltype(auto) _Emplace_back_with_unused_capacity(_Valty&&... _Val) {
        // insert by perfectly forwarding into element at end, provide strong guarantee
        auto& _My_data   = _Mypair._Myval2;
        pointer& _Mylast = _My_data._Mylast;
        _STL_INTERNAL_CHECK(_Mylast != _My_data._Myend); // check that we have unused capacity
        _Alty_traits::construct(_Getal(), _Unfancy(_Mylast), _STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
        _Orphan_range(_Mylast, _Mylast);
        _Ty& _Result = *_Mylast;
        ++_Mylast;
#if _HAS_CXX17
        return _Result;
#else // ^^^ _HAS_CXX17 ^^^ // vvv !_HAS_CXX17 vvv
        (void) _Result;
#endif // _HAS_CXX17
    }
```

After inline and other optimizations, the STL code doesn't seem to make much difference from mine.

Could anyone tell me why is my push_back is more efficient(or why STL is slow)?

EDIT:
Sorry, my question seemd to caused a misunderstanding.

I know that `std::vector` is general, so it might do more work than mine.

But in a `push_back` of type `int` , I don't think `std::vector` did something special, so why it is slow?

Comment: are you actually creating/copying objects? `realloc` / `malloc` merely allocates memory.

Comment: in `push_back()` , a int is copied @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: `static_assert((std::is_trivial_v<T>), "Array requires type to be trivial.");` thats not what a `std::vector` is. You can always remove functionality and gain performance. The tricky part is to comply with specification of `std::vector` *and*  be more efficient than some existing implementation

Comment: try to use yours with `std::string`. I am not sure where, but I am almost certain that it will blow up

Comment: The measured difference could be entirely incidental, caused by differences in layout of the memory. Also, what is the variance of the measurements? How about sample size?

Comment: I know what you mean, but in a `push_back` its not the matter @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: btw "more effective" would be eg if your push_back would push two elements instead of just one. You mean "efficient"

Comment: of course it matters for `push_back`. When requested size exceeds current capacity you need to reallocate and move elements. And you merely allocate memory, thats not sufficient in general

Comment: But I reserved enough memory previously @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: C++ objects are not just some bytes of memory. You need to create them.

Comment: But a int is trully some bytes of memory @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: Strictly speaking, no, it isn't

Comment: yes, your vectors looks fine for trivial types (I think), but `std::vector` can do much more. More is never for free

Comment: Actully when I use resize instead of reserve , I got the same result

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 `You need to create them` Not anymore, as trivial objects can be created implicitly since P0593R6 was accepted into the standard as a defect resolution. Malloc and assign is now officially OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is mainly due to less favorable codegen in the `std::vector` version. We can see it if we compare the generated assembly ([godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ofPxcnKhn)).

Your loop (skipping the reallocation part):

```
$LL4@test:
        xor     esi, esi
        xor     edi, edi
$LL7@test:
        mov     r15, rbx
        cmp     rdi, rbx
        jne     SHORT $LN27@test
        <...skip...>
$LN27@test:
        mov     DWORD PTR [r14+rdi*4], esi
        inc     rdi
        inc     esi
        cmp     esi, 100000                         ; 000186a0H
        jl      $LL7@test
        sub     r12, r13
        jne     $LL4@test
```

`std::vector::push_back` loop (again, skipping the reallocation part):

```
$LL4@test:
        xor     ebx, ebx
        mov     DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], ebx
$LL7@test:
        cmp     rcx, QWORD PTR v$[rsp+16]
        je      SHORT $LN26@test
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], ebx
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR v$[rsp+8]
        add     rcx, 4
        mov     QWORD PTR v$[rsp+8], rcx
        jmp     SHORT $LN5@test
$LN26@test:
        <...skip...>
$LN5@test:
        inc     ebx
        mov     DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], ebx
        cmp     ebx, 100000                         ; 000186a0H
        jl      SHORT $LL7@test
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR v$[rsp]
        mov     QWORD PTR v$[rsp+8], rcx
        sub     rdi, 1
        jne     SHORT $LL4@test
```

Clearly we can see more code (11 vs. 8 instructions in the hot path) and more indirection to memory (5 vs. 1). So it's no surprise that it's slower.

More generally, more complex code == slower code.

Could the two versions be optimized identically? I see no reason why not. MSVC 19.28 just can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your version is only valid for trivially copyable types.

> Because reallocation may involve bytewise copying (regardless of whether it's to expand or to contract), only the objects of *[TriviallyCopyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable)* types are safe to access in the preserved part of the memory block after a call to `realloc`.

The ordinary `std::vector` has a very lax requirement in comparions, merely *[Destructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Destructible)* in general, and one of *[CopyInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyInsertable)* or *[MoveInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable)* for `push_back`.

Comment: But I reserved enough memory previously, and when I use resize instead of reserve , I got the same result

Comment: @victor12369 you need to understand that you only considered a very narrow use case. `std::vector` can do much more, your vector cannot. Far fetched analogy: `2+2 == 2*2`, but you would not conclude that we can now always use `+` instead of `*`, because they yield the same result anyhow, while `+` is much simpler

Comment: `realloc`ing an array of `std::string` is undefined behaviour

Comment: But `std::vector` won't do more in `push_back` , @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: `std::vector<int>` won't, but `std::vector<std::string>` will

Comment: @victor12369 we are turning in circles..... `std::vector<std::string>` is a thing. `Array<std::string>` fails immediately

Comment: but in my code, I use `vector<int>` and get the result, ---I'm talking about `std::vector<int>::push_back` actually

Comment: @victor12369 so what? You should not be surprised by finding a specific use case where you can write customized code tailored for that use case that performs better than general purpose library code

Comment: Yes, and we are saying that MSVC's authors (potentially) traded performance in this case for generality in not specialising the `vector` temlate for trivial types

Comment: You will also have to be careful about all the places that might have undefined behaviour in your implementation

Comment: Please see the code in MSVC STL, actually it do not do something special, I mean my code is nealy equal to MSVC's

Comment: You are ignoring `_Emplace_reallocate`, i.e. the tricky part

Comment: No, actually it won't invoked , because I reserved enough memory @Caleth

Comment: Then in my code `if (m_siz == m_cap)increase(m_cap + 1);`included too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232214/discussion-between-caleth-and-victor12369).

Comment: emm...  I can't join the chat room, might because of my net?

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely possible that the measured difference is incidental, due to a different layout in memory. The layout has a huge effect on the performance, and it can be affected by many things besides the implementation of the vector.

I ran your benchmark on another system, and your vector took 31% longer time to complete than the standard one. Admittedly, the vector implementation was different - libstdc++. But this doesn't mean that libstdc++ vector is faster than your vector which is faster than MSVC vector. The benchmark simply isn't intricate enough to determine that with confidence.

Answer (score 0):

It is more that MSVC's STL has a suboptimal implementation. It could also be a suboptimal compiler optimizer of the visual studio compiler.

See: https://godbolt.org/z/rT5Kaao7G for a small testcase:

```cpp
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void foo(vector<int> &vec, const vector<int> &input) {
    vec.reserve(10000);
    for (int i : input) {
        vec.emplace_back(i);
    }
}
```

gcc optimizes it better than MSVC. gcc is so clever that it converts the entire for loop into a `memmove`.

```
.L34:
        mov     rsi, r14
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    memmove
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbp+16]
        sub     rsi, r14
```

MSVC calls the `emblace_back` implementation (`_Emplace_reallocate`) in a loop which is not something i'd expect from a modern optimizing compiler.

```
$LL4@foo:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], eax
        cmp     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
        je      SHORT $LN9@foo
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
        add     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], 4
        jmp     SHORT $LN2@foo
$LN9@foo:
        lea     r8, QWORD PTR i$1[rsp]
        mov     rcx, rdi
        call    int * std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::_Emplace_reallocate<int &>(int * const,int &) ; std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::_Emplace_reallocate<int &>
$LN2@foo:
        add     rbx, 4
        cmp     rbx, rsi
        jne     SHORT $LL4@foo
```